# var doesn't equal null, but it should

Tags: kotlin

what i do after compiling is, insted of writing something in readLine, i press enter(return) so this should make bevarage equal null so i should see "variable beverage equal null" and "Buttered Ale" but what i see is nothing (empty lines), it seems like beverage is NOT equal null, why? and how do i fix it to make beverage equal null?

```
fun main()  {
    var beverage:String? = readLine()
    if(beverage !=null){
        beverage =beverage .capitalize()
    }else{
        println("variable beverage equal null")
    }
    val beverageServed: String = beverage ?: "Buttered Ale"
    println(beverageServed)
}
```

Comment: If you type enter, then you don't close the stream. You just enter an empty line. So readLine() returns this empty line, not null.

Comment: @JBNizet so how to make beverage equal null?

Comment: Close the stream (if your console supports it, Ctrl-D should do that, AFAIK). Or test if the string is empty instead of checking if it's null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy that you know Elvis operator but this time, to fix the bug I propose a classic if / else to have a more functional test which cover the case where you enter nothing

Hence replacethis line : `val beverageServed: String = beverage ?: "Buttered Ale"`

By this one : 
`val beverageServed: String = if ((beverage != null) && (beverage != "")) beverage else "Buttered Ale"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking null equality, use `isNullOrBlank` or `isNullOrEmpty`:

```
var beverage: String? = readLine()
if (beverage.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    beverage = beverage.capitalize()
}
```

You could also use more nullable chaining for a brevity:

```
println(
    beverage
        ?.ifBlank { null }
        ?.capitalize()
        ?: "Buttered Ale"
)
```